# C - Pointers and Arrays in Different Methods

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am still new to learning how to use pointers and such, and I was wondering if someone could help me as I am not sure how I could do the thing that I want to.

What I am trying to do is have 3 methods, a main, a getArray and printArray that the getArray should be using pointers. The array must be 2D. For example:

```
void main() {
    char *array[10];
    array[0] = malloc(10);
    getArray(&array[0]);
    printArray(array[0]);
}

void getArray(char *array) {
    scanf("%s", array); //or &array?
}

void printArray(char array[]) {
    printf("%s", array);
}
```

I tried using this code above, and when I used as an input: "a" it returned this

```
a
o
--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.3538 seconds with return value 2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm still rather new to pointers, and I'm not really that sure how to use them. Sorry.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you get any warnings when compiling this code?

Comment: You need to study some basics about pointers and arrays in C. This is so messed up that it is basically pointless to start to explain all the problems. No offense.

Comment: Please compile with **warnings** enabled. No compliant modern C compiler will compile this without issuing any diagnostics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getArray(&array[0]);` You are passing `char**`.

In your program you have undefined behavior passing the wrong argument  `scanf()`. `scanf()` tries to read the characters read into the address contained in `array` which is not the one you allocated. This is why you get undefined behavior. `scanf()` expects a `char*` and you passed `char**`.

**Solution**: `getArray(array[0]);`

Also in the method passing `array` would be alright as it contains the address where you will read the string.

---

Apart from all this:

You didn't check the return value of `malloc` which you should. And free that memory after yo are done working with it.

If you have checked the warning then it says

```
note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```

This should have given you enough idea about what is going on.

As pointed out by Jonathan Leffler Also declare (or define) the function before you use them. As pointed out,then you will get type mismatch error. This is required by C99 or later versions. (C90 allowed it - calling a function before declaring). The implicit declaration considered would be `int getArray()`.

Comment: And declare (or define) the functions before you use them.  You would then get type mismatch errors.  Modern C requires that (C99 or later). Only archaic C (C90) allows you to call functions that have not been declared.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: Edited - using gcc compiler it shows error that it is getting type mismatch with implicitly declared functions (2 for each - one for return type another for arguments)..OP is using C90 I guess